# react.js formik and yup multiple error display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I am trying to validate using formik and yup on react.js. In the schema I created for yup, there is an email and password section, I just want to **show all the errors in the password section at the same time, the errors in the email section should be displayed in order**, but I couldn't do it, but I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Here is how I created the yup object

```
 const validationPageTwo = Yup.object({
   email: Yup.string().required("Required field"),
   password: Yup.string()
  .required("Required field password")
  .matches(/^(?=.{8,})/, "Must Contain 8 Characters")
  .matches(/^(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])/, " One Special Case Character")
  .matches(/^(?=.*[0-9])/, " One Number")
  .matches(/^(?=.*[a-z])/, " One Lowercase")
  .matches(/^(?=.*[A-Z])/, " One Uppercase"),
 });



const formik = useFormik({
 initialValues: {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
 },
 validationSchema: page === 1 ? validationPageOne : 
 validationPageTwo,
 onSubmit: (values) => {
  if (page === 1) {
    setPage(2);
  } else {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  }
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I finally solved the problem, if you want you can use it as a schema in formic and map all errors separately.  Thanks to everyone who helped me solve the problem

```
const validationPageTwo = Yup.object({
email: Yup.string().required("Required field").email(),
password: Yup.string()
  .required("Required field password")
  .test({
    test: (value) => {
      let errors = [];

      if (!/^(?=.{8,})/.test(value)) {
        errors.push("Must Contain 8 Characters");
      }

      if (!/^(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])/.test(value)) {
        errors.push("One Special Case Character");
      }

      if (!/^(?=.*[0-9])/.test(value)) {
        errors.push("One Number");
      }

      if (!/^(?=.*[a-z])/.test(value)) {
        errors.push("One Lowercase");
      }

      if (!/^(?=.*[A-Z])/.test(value)) {
        errors.push("One Uppercase");
      }

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        throw new Yup.ValidationError({
          errors: errors,
          inner: true,
          path: "password",
          message: errors,
          value: value,
          name: "ValidationError",
        });
      }

      return true;
    },
  }),
 });



const formik = useFormik({
 initialValues: {
   email: "",
   password: "",
},
validationSchema:validationPageTwo,
onSubmit: (values) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
},
});



 const { errors } = formik;

console.log(errors.password);
```